# Macro to forward emails

Tags: vba, outlook

Where I work, the faxes sent from customers arrive in the mailbox of the reception computer, as emails with a fax attached. The faxes are then forwarded to the respective Public Folder.

We need to send a confirmation email to the customer after forwarding to the public folder. We do this by creating buttons in Outlook, programmed to send a confirmation email as well as forward the email to the right public folder.

Quite often we find the buttons used to forward faxes have "disappeared". Restarting Outlook brings the buttons back. However, we receive a fair amount of faxes, therefore it isn't efficient to restart Outlook after forwarding every fax.

I can't post the code as it was written in house. Does anyone know of any kind of set up other than this that's proven to work time and time again? Which I could then implement into our system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest developing an Outlook add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started. But even in that case nobody can guarantee that your code will not be disabled.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

See [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) for more information.

Make sure that your code doesn't generate exceptions...